# Testing a scroll method

Tags: javascript, testing, scroll

I need to test a method called `scrollToBottom` which does the following:

```
this.getMainElem().scrollTop = this.getMainElem().scrollHeight;
```

Since a new element has no `scrollHeight` or `scrollTop` value until it has been pasted onto the DOM, how can I test my method? At the moment, I have to create a new element with text, a height and overflow auto then append it directly to `document.body`.

Can you suggest a cleaner way of testing this?

Comment: You could use the method `console.log("myText");`, which prints whatever you want to see on console. To access the console : **right clic** on your page, select **inspect element** and then clic on the tab **console** to see what is printed.

Comment: True, but this is for tests that we run regularly, not ad-hoc testing locally.